# How to Use getMaintenanceWindows method by using a SoftLayer REST API

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

please tell me how to get available maintenance windows by using a SoftLayer REST API.
I tried it in the following way, but it did not work.

> curl -K support -d @Maintence.json -X POST https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Provisioning_Maintenance_Window/getMaintenceWindows

When executing the command, the following error message is displayed:

> {"error":"End date must be a later date than begin
>   date.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception"}

The contents of the JSON file are described below:

```
 {
    "parameters":[ 
    { 
         "beginDate": "2016-12-22T00:00",
          "endDate": "2016-12-29T00:00",
         "locationId": 138124,
         "slotsNeeded" : 1
    }]
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper API to use here is [SoftLayer_Provisioning_Maintenance_Window::getMaintenanceWindows()](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Provisioning_Maintenance_Window/getMaintenanceWindows/) as opposed to the misspelled `getMaintenceWindows`

The API payload is still the same.

```sh
curl -K support -d @Maintence.json -X POST https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Provisioning_Maintenance_Window/getMaintenanceWindows
```

```json
{
    "parameters":[ 

         "2016-12-22T00:00",
         "2016-12-29T00:00",
         138124,
         1
    ]
 }
```

When making API calls to the softlayer API, the parameters are not named, just listed in order that matches the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to send the parameters (It's not necesary to define them in an object), so try with this json:

```
{
    "parameters":[ 

         "2016-12-22T00:00",
         "2016-12-29T00:00",
         138124,
         1
    ]
 }
```

**References:**

- [SoftLayer_Provisioning_Maintenance_Window::getMaintenceWindows](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Provisioning_Maintenance_Window/getMaintenceWindows)